# Error FS0752 in F# declaration of a map over list of functions

Tags: f#, f#-interactive

I would like to execute a list of functions over a list of corresponding values:

```
let f1 x = x*2;;  
let f2 x = x+70;;

let conslist = [f1;f2];;

let pmap2 list1 list2 =   
  seq { for i in 0..1 do yield async { return list1.[i] list2.[i] } }  
  |> Async.Parallel  
  |> Async.RunSynchronously;;
```

Result:

```
  seq { for i in 0..1 do yield async { return list1.[i] list2.[i] } }
----------------------------------------------^^^^^^^^^
```

> stdin(213,49): error FS0752: The
>   operator 'expr.[idx]' has been used an
>   object of indeterminate type based on
>   information prior to this program
>   point. Consider adding further type
>   constraints

I would like to execute: pmap2 conslist [5;8];; (in parallel)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want to use random access then you should use arrays. Random access to elements of list will work, but it is inefficient (it needs to iterate over the list from the start). A version using arrays would look like this:

```
// Needs to be declared as array
let conslist = [|f1; f2|];; 

// Add type annotations to specify that arguments are arrays
let pmap2 (arr1:_[]) (arr2:_[]) = 
  seq { for i in 0 .. 1 do 
          yield async { return arr1.[i] arr2.[i] } }
  |> Async.Parallel |> Async.RunSynchronously
```

However, you can also rewrite the example to work with any sequences (including arrays and lists) using the `Seq.zip` function. I think this solution is more elegant and it doesn't force you to use imperative arrays (and it doesn't have the performance disadvantage):

```
// Works with any sequence type (array, list, etc.)
let pmap2 functions arguments = 
  seq { for f, arg in Seq.zip functions arguments do 
          yield async { return f arg } }
  |> Async.Parallel |> Async.RunSynchronously
```

Comment: Great, complete answer; much better than what I managed to scrawl out from my phone earlier this morning.  :)

Answer (score 3):

As the error message suggests, you need to add type annotations to `list1` and `list2`. Once you do that, it works fine (though I would recommend using arrays instead of list since you're random-accessing them).

Answer (score 1):

```
let pmap2 (list1:_ list) (list2:_ list)
```