# writing methods in f#

Tags: c, f#

I have a question:

There is such a method in C:

```
inline void ColorSet(int face, int pos,int col)
{
  color[face*9+pos]=col;
}
```

I've tried to write it in F#;

```ml
type ColorSet =
    member this.ColorSet (face: int, pos: int, col: int) = 
        color.[face*9+pos] = col
```

but I encountered with such an error:

> The operator `'expr.[idx]'` has been used on an object of indeterminate type based on information prior to this program point. Consider adding further type constraints...

Could you help me to write the exact method?

Comment: what is the error, please?

Comment: I'm not knowledgable about `f#`, but it looks like the problem is in `color.[face*9+pos]` part. where did you define `color`? Maybe it's having a problem with the definition.

Comment: let color = Array.init<byte> (6*9)

Comment: See, as I already mentioned, i don't know the `f#` language, you check twice yourself or wait for someone knowledgable. but from a simple analysis, `color` being a `byte`, can it store an `int col`? however, i may be very wrong, as I have no idea of `f#` datatype.

Comment: Actually I've changed byto to int, but the same problem appears in that case as well.

Comment: well, then , I'm clueless. :-) maybe you can check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4843445/2173917) answer.

Comment: Can you give us a complete example by showing us where `color` is defined relative to the class definition?

Comment: let color = Array.init<byte> (6*9)

Comment: @Yusuf as noted by the answers, what we needed was how it was defined *_relative_* to the class definition.  Inference has precedence etc, so we have to guess what you're doing if you don't give us a complete example.

Comment: you are right mydogisbox, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reading the comments, it seems you may be trying to do this:

```ml
let itemCount = 9
let faceCount = 6

let color : int [] = Array.zeroCreate (faceCount * itemCount)

let setColor face pos col =
    color.[face * itemCount + pos] <- col
```

Two things to note:

- The *object of indeterminate type* error can usually be solved with a type annotation: by declaring `color` as `: int []`, it is specified that color must be an array of integers
- The operator `=` is a test for equality in F#. To assign to a mutable variable or an array component, use `<-`.

Usage might look like this:

```ml
let red = 0xFFFF0000 // Assuming ARGB (machine endianness)
setColor 0 8 red // Set the last component of the first face to red
```

Note that this is unusual style for F#. I do use code like this, but only if it is known to be performance critical and the compiler can't optimize it. Normally, you would use a type for color, e.g. System.Drawing.Color for compatibility, and a type for the objects iterated by the `face` parameter.

---

**Edit** Are you storing the colors of 6 faces of dice or cuboids interleaved in an array? Just in case someone is interested, I'll assume that and write how it might look in more typical F#. *I don't know if this is relevant, but I guess it can't hurt to add it.*

```ml
/// A color, represented as an int. Format, from most to least
/// significant byte: alpha, red, green, blue
type Color = Color of int

let black = Color 0xFF000000
let red   = Color 0xFFFF0000

type CubeColors =
    { Top   : Color; Bottom : Color
      Left  : Color; Right  : Color
      Front : Color; Back   : Color }

    /// Creates CubeColors where all faces have the same color
    static member Uniform c =
        { Top=c; Bottom=c; Left=c 
          Right=c; Front=c; Back=c }

// Make an array with nine completely black cubes
let cubes = Array.create 9 (CubeColors.Uniform black)

// Change the top of the second cube to red
cubes.[1] <- { cubes.[1] with Top = red }
```

This uses a single-case [discriminated union](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233226%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for the `Color` type and a [record](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233184.aspx) for the `CubeColors` type. This is much safer to use, and often more readable, than doing low-level array stuff.

Answer (score 0):

You should define `color` somewhere in the class constructor.
For example if `color` is an array:

```
type ColorSet() =
    let color = Array.zeroCreate 100
    member this.ColorSet (face: int, pos: int, col: int) = 
        color.[face*9+pos] <- col
```

Comment: The `=` operator is an equality check in F#, but an assignment to a mutable variable in C. The F# code would have to use `<-` to do an assignment.

Comment: Thank you Petr and Vandroiy :)

Comment: But Petr, I cannot use in this way? let color = Array.init<byte> (6*9)

let ColorSet (face: int, pos: int, col: int) = 
    color.[face*9+pos] = col Because in this way I still get the same error.

Comment: As Vandroiy mentioned assignment operator in F# is `<-` not `=`.  Also if you created byte array you should assign bytes to its values but your `col` parameter is of type `int`